# Drawing app in Android

Tags: android

Can any one Help me how to make drawing app in android in which i can draw line,square  etc....?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of general question; SO questions tend to be about specific problems with a narrow scope. That said, it sounds like you're new to programming and the best advice I can give is to look at the examples that come with the android SDK. There is a drawing app example that should provide you with all the basics you need.

have a look at

```
API Demos -> Graphics -> TouchPaint
```

There are other examples which cover line drawing and so on.
 If, after looking at the examples and trying to alter their functionality, you still have problems then you can ask more specific questions here.

Good luck.

Comment: i want to make app in which i can draw line sqare circle and points and random drawing etc

Comment: Yes, you said that. Have you looked at the example I listed above?

Comment: @Nirav If you want to make an app make it, no ones stopping. They have already told you *how* to go about it. We dont entertain give me the codez questions. Ask something more specific.

Comment: okiii i will take care next time thnx for suggetion....

Answer (score 2):

Stuff you would need:

1. Gesture recognition - resizing, tapping, dragging etc.
2. Use a 2D surface for drawing. You can use a custom view and then draw on it by overriding the onDraw method.
3. Buttons to select what you want to draw.

Basically, detect gesture -> calculate changes in your view -> invalidate the view by calling **invalidate()** -> Redraw new view.

Here is a tutorial: http://marakana.com/tutorials/android/2d-graphics-example.html