# Android - canvas confusion (drawing and scrolling)

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm having a bit of confusion with `canvas` in android and was wondering if someone could clarify a few things for me.

I currently have this code inside my View class:

```
 class HomerView extends View { // the custom View for drawing on
    // set up Bitmap, canvas, path and paint
    private Bitmap myBitmap; // the initial image we turn into our canvas
    private Canvas myCanvas; // the canvas we are drawing on
    private Rect myRect; // the mathematical path of the lines we draw
    private Paint myBitmapPaint; // the paint we use to draw the bitmap

    // get the width of the entire tablet screen
    private int screenWidth = getContext().getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    // get the height of the entire tablet screen
    private int screenHeight = getContext().getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

    private int mX, mY, iX, iY; // current x,y and initial x,y
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;
    private BitmapDrawable mImage;
    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

    public HomerView(Context context) { // constructor of HomerView
        super(context);
        myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // set our drawable space - the bitmap which becomes the canvas we draw on
        myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap); // set our canvas to our bitmap which we just set up
        myRect = new Rect(); // make a new rect
        myBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG); // set dither to ON in our saved drawing - gives better color interaction
        setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.View);
        initializeScrollbars(a);
        a.recycle();
        computeVerticalScrollRange();
        computeHorizontalScrollRange();
        mImage = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), myBitmap);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context,
                new ScaleListener());
    }

    public HomerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context,
                new ScaleListener());
    }

    public HomerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { // method used when we want to draw something to our canvas
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (addObjectMode == true) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); // sets canvas colour
            canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, myBitmapPaint); // save the canvas to bitmap - the numbers are the x, y coords we are drawing from
            canvas.drawRect(myRect, myPaint); // draw the rectangle that the user has drawn using the paint we set up
        } else if (moveMode == true) {
            canvas.save();
            System.out.println("X: " + mPosX + " Y: " + mPosY);
            canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
            canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
            mImage.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }
```

This is kind of an amalgamation of 2 different approaches to drawing to the screen as I understand it. My understanding is that I have `myBitmap` (which is what users drawings are drawn on) and this works fine for *"addObjectMode"*. However, *"moveMode"* is when I want the users to be able to pinch zoom scroll etc. around the house plan that they have drawn.

Currently, I am able to draw objects fine but when I press the button to enable `moveMode`, the drawing disappears when I touch or gesture. I'm aware this is probably because of the code in `onDraw()`; but canvas's are still a bit of a mystery to me.

Eventually, I'm going to want a basic undo/redo feature as well as saving the `canvas/bitmap` to be opened later. Can anyone offer any advice or link to any comprehensive canvas tutorials?

EDIT: it might be useful to include my `onTouchEvent` methods too-

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { // on any touch event
        if (addObjectMode == true) {

            float x = event.getX(); // get current X
            float y = event.getY(); // get current Y

            switch (event.getAction()) { // what action is the user performing?
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // if user is touching down
                touch_Start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // if user is moving finger while touched down
                touch_Move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // if user has released finger
                touch_Up();
                invalidate();
                break;
            }
            return true;
        } else if (moveMode == true) {
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            final int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final float x = event.getX();
                final float y = event.getY();
                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                final int pointerIndex = event
                        .findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                final float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
                final float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);

                // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
                if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                    final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                    final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;
                    mPosX += dx;
                    mPosY += dy;
                    invalidate();
                }
                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                final int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                    // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mLastTouchX = event.getX(newPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY = event.getY(newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                }
                break;
            }
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, when your in moveMode, you don't draw anything on your final canvas.

Even if your are applying transformations on something that was already drawn, be aware that the canvas is clear between two calls of onDraw() so you have do draw it again.

I'm not familiar with the undo redo feature, but you should be able to store a copy of the canvas's bitmap at a given point to restore it later

[Bitmap.copy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copy%28android.graphics.Bitmap.Config,%20boolean%29)

be carefull that storing a large amount of bitmaps can be quite heavy for mobile environment so you'll have to limit the undo stack size.

Comment: Ah...doesn't the line `mImage.draw(canvas);` draw to canvas? What I've done instead is added `    canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, myBitmapPaint);` before canvas.restore(); It kind of works although when I then pinch zoom and switch to "drawing mode" it immediately reverts back to the initial zoom level as if no scrolling had occurred. Any idea why?

Comment: yes, in the same way your drawing were not apply to your movemode, your translate transformations are not applied to your drawMode here ;)

Comment: I suggest you separate the move / draw mecanism out from the draw method, manage to draw it on a unique output bitmap on user events. then on the onDraw method only draw the output bitmap.

Comment: I'll try what you suggested but I'm still having trouble getting my head around the way canvas and drawing works at this level. Any good resources/tutorials for this? @Guian

Comment: A similar question exists to find 'Paint like' application source code and learn from it,  see the answer here :http://stackoverflow.com/a/8155067/1489009

Comment: this one also, referencing the android's API Demo : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5258538/1489009

Answer (score 0):

remove the `if else if` condition on draw method, and for undo feature make a arraylist of bitmap, and save your bitmap every time user does some action, then on undo replace the bitmap to previous and invalidate the view

Comment: I want the user to have 2 "touch modes" - drawing and moving. The if else is there to execute the relevant code on touch. Without the `if else if` I can draw but when in moveMode, nothing happens.

Comment: if you are in moveing mode, why are skipping the drawing mode?  first draw the thing the bitmap, and the scale it

Comment: Drawing mode = the user draws rectangles, Movement mode = the user can pinch zoom & scroll around their rectangles.

Comment: yes boss, i know what you are saying, Dont remove the if condition in on touch event but remove the condition in onDraw method

Comment: Ah! I was misunderstanding sorry! I removed the `if else` but experience a different kind of error now... What happens is that after I draw a rectangle and try to move it - I seem to move a copy of the original while the original rectangle remains in place. Also if I try to draw another rectangle after moving, it is drawn relative to the original and not the moved or zoomed in copy.

Comment: that is because you are not zooming your drawing canvas (containg bitmap)

Comment: How would I zoom my drawing canvas? I want to be able to zoom in but then draw and not have it revert to the original zoom/bitmap.

Comment: use matrix to zoom the canvas first

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement Undo\Redo you need to maintain pathlist... and you have to store those paths in your pathlist accordingly. I have attached my code below, have a look at it then you will get some clear Idea about undo redo functionality.

```
     public static LinkedList<Path> rrPathList=new LinkedList<Path>();
     public static LinkedList<Path> mPathList=new LinkedList<Path>();
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            for( i = 0; i < mPathList.size() && i < sPaint.size(); i++ )
            {
                canvas.drawPath(mPathList.get(i),sPaint.get(i));

            }
          }
   // In your touch up method store the paths into mPathList
        private void touch_up() {     
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            mPathList.add(mPath);  
        }
   // Undo function
     public void undo()
    {
        try
        {
            if(mPathList.size()>0)
            {
                rPathList.add(mPathList.getLast());
                mPathList.removeLast();

                 invalidate();
            }
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException arr)
        {
          //Print error;
        }
    }
     // Redo function
     public void redo()
    {
        try
        {
            if(rPathList.size()>0)
            {
                mPathList.add(rPathList.getLast());
                rPathList.removeLast();
             invalidate();
            }
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException arr)
        {
            //Handle error
        }
    }
```

Note: Please do not forget to call "invalidate()". 
Calling invalidate results " Call the canvas and redraw the mPathList Objects"
Try this. I am working with this code...
Thank you!!!